# Why does x86 have the redundant JNGE instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, history

On page 3-431 of the [Intel instruction set reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf), two different instructions are mentioned:

```
7C cb  JL rel8   Jump short if less (SF ≠ OF).
7C cb  JNGE rel8 Jump short if not greater or equal (SF ≠ OF).
```

What is the reasoning behind having two names for the same instruction? Is there any instance where it matters whether I use `JL` or `JNGE`?

Comment: I doubt it matters as the assembler will produce the same machine code for both, therefore logically the exact same effect. Interesting quirk though

Comment: @geedubb Well, *my* and *your* assembler produce the same result, but maybe some assembler didn't?

Comment: @HansPassant `JL` is the same as `JNGE`, both are signed. You might be thinking of `JB` and `JNAE` which are the unsigned counterparts.

Comment: @phihag that would be a broken assember then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just to make code more readable in case one or the other matches your intention better. As you quoted, the machine code is the same, and ultimately that's what the processor will execute. As such, it won't know whether you used `JL` or `JNGE`. All the relations have their negated name too.

There are other duplicates that illustrate the readability point a little better, for example `JE` and `JZ`. You'd normally use `JE` after a comparison, and `JZ` otherwise. Similarly you have `JB` and `JC`.